# v-tabs: Using arrows to change tabs

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js

I'm quite new to vue.js and I would like to ask if it's possible to change tabs (contents) using the arrows? I'm using v-tabs with show-arrows="true".

[image: Tab Photo]

Currently, I have to click on the text (for e.g. Monday) to change content.

My ideal output is to click the left and right arrow to change the tab (content).

*E.g. Clicking the right arrow will change to Tuesday's content.*

Thank you! :)

```
    <div class="container--fluid days-header">
      <div>
        <v-card width="250" flat tile>
          <v-tabs
            show-arrows="true"
            dark
            background-color="grey darken-3"
            center-active
            v-model="activeDay"
          >
            <!-- <v-tabs-slider color="grey lighten-3"></v-tabs-slider> -->

            <v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="newDay(item.id)">{{item.name}}</v-tab>
          </v-tabs>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Sorry! Updated with the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the `slide-group` component along with the `tabs`...

```js
<v-slide-group center-active show-arrows v-model="activeDay">
        <template v-slot:prev>
            <v-btn text @click="prev()"><v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon></v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-slide-item v-for="d in items" :key="d.id" v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }">
            <v-btn class="mx-2"
                :input-value="active" 
                active-class="purple white--text" 
                depressed 
                @click="setActive(d.id)"> {{ d.name }}
            </v-btn>
        </v-slide-item>
        <template v-slot:next>
           <v-btn text @click="next()"><v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon></v-btn>
        </template>
</v-slide-group>
<v-tabs show-arrows="true" v-model="activeDay">
        <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">{{item.name}}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/MR3Sajw9kt

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! This solution solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a native vuetify solution but you can do this with some good old vanilla javascript.

On `mounted` you could create a clickEvent on the next/previous arrow and handle the change yourself. So whenever the icon gets clicked,the `activeDay` gets increased or decreased by one.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeDay: 0,
      items: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // setup click event for next icon
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("v-slide-group__next")[0]
      .addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.activeDay++;
      });
    // setup click event for previous icon
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("v-slide-group__prev")[0]
      .addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.activeDay--;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```